# No Connection in mysql workbench 6.3

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am not able to connect to mysql workbench database..... It shows no connection [This is the screen shot when I try to connect to localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TaOP.png)

Comment: Does it connect via terminal using the mysql command line?

Comment: Its resolved now - yeah there was something wrong with my command line client as well . When I used to enter password, the window used to shut down immediately. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mohsen B : Yes my problem is now solved. This usually happens when we only download the partial components of my sql and not the complete package, because of which the mysql server installed on our system does not start automatically or in some cases is either not installed....Use this video for reference of installing mysql on your system.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZqZClGf_-DA

Comment: I recommend using the [MySQL Installer for Windows](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/5.7.html). It installs, configures, and updates all of the MySQL components.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @Punita , I just deleted the last table I had created from the C: drive , then restarted Mysql from Controlpanel/Administrativetools/Services and now everything is ok. Thanks for your help.